# How to solve this PDE $(x-y)\partial_x\partial_yu-\partial_xu+\partial_yu=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How do I solve this partial differential equation
$$(x-y)\partial_x\partial_yu-\partial_xu+\partial_yu=0$$

I know how to solve
$$\partial_x\partial_yu=0$$

The solution to this should be $u=f(x)+g(y)$, however I don't know how to solve it when there are other terms in the equation. Should I go for some $\xi(x,y),\eta(x,y)$ substitution or is there some other way ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $z:=x-y$ so $\partial_z=\partial_x-\partial_y$ and $-z\partial_xv-v=0$ with $v:=\partial_zu$, i.e. $v=f(z)\exp(-x/z)$ with $f$ arbitrary. The "integration constant" in the indefinite integral $u=\int f(z)\exp(-x/z)dz$ is an arbitrary function of $x$.